# Does Microdata have to be visible to the visitor to be displayed in Google search results?

Tags: html, google-search, microdata, rich-snippets, hidden-text

Does Microdata (for rich snippets) have to be visible to the visitor to be displayed in Google search results?

I want to add the rich snippet to my page, but I don't want it in the format that is required. So I thought I could add it as a hidden `div`, but I'm not sure if that will work.

```html
<div style="visibility:hidden;height:0px;" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
<div itemprop="name"><asp:Literal ID="ltTitle" runat="server" /></div>
<div itemprop="description"><asp:Literal ID="ltMetadescription" runat="server" /></div>
<div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
    <span itemprop="streetAddress"><asp:Literal ID="ltAddress" runat="server" /></span>
    <span itemprop="postalCode"><asp:Literal ID="ltZipcode" runat="server" /></span> 
    <span itemprop="addressLocality"><asp:Literal ID="ltCity" runat="server" /></span>
    <span itemprop="addressRegion"><asp:Literal ID="ltProvince" runat="server" /></span> 
    <span itemprop="addressCountry"><asp:Literal ID="ltCountry" runat="server" /></span>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Related: [Can microdata be implemented in meta tags?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/71555/can-microdata-be-implemented-in-meta-tags). You [might want to](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/82114/17633) use JSON-LD instead of Microdata.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your rich snippet data needs to be visible to users.  From [Google's rich snippet troubleshooting](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1093493#hidden):

> **Is your marked-up content hidden from users?**
>
> In general, Google won't display any content in rich snippets that is not visible to human user. It can be tempting to add all the content relevant for a rich snippet in one place on the page, mark it up, and then hide the entire block of text using techniques like display:none, value-title, css etc. Don't do it! Google will ignore content that isn't visible to human users, so you should mark up the text that visitors will see on your web pages.
>
> Note that in a few limited circumstances, it can be useful to provide both a machine-readable and a human-readable version of your content. For example, because the text string "Elvis's birthday" is significant to a great many human readers, but less so to machines, Google provides a way to provide the date in a machine-readable form—1935-01-08—while still displaying the content in a human-friendly way. For more information, check the Help article for each product type.