# How can I add schema.org microdata to a site without displaying it on the page?

Tags: schema.org, structured-data

I am adding microdata to a site which displays events. After running it through Google's Structured Data Tester, it tells me that I need to include address information for the event venue. If I use:

```
<td itemprop="location" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Place">
    <a href="#" target="_blank">Hooville</a>
        <div itemprop="address">
            <meta itemprop="addressLocality" >Anystate, USA</meta>
        </div>
</td>
```

It displays 'Anystate, USA' on the page - I don't want this to happen. I've tried:

```
<td itemprop="location" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Place">
    <a href="#" target="_blank">Hooville</a>
        <div itemprop="address">
            <meta itemprop="addressLocality" content="Anystate, USA">
        </div>
</td>
```

But the SDT then no longer finds the address. So, how can I add in the address data without actually displaying it?

EDIT: after a quick look I note that Google doesn't like the use of meta tags to hide content, and that it doesn't like hidden content full stop. So I am between a rock and a hard place - I don't want to display full address details in that part of the site, but the SDT says it should be there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

- you use `meta`, but correctly, like me:

`<div itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Place">
       <meta itemprop="name" content="Hooville" >
       <a href="http://www.example.com" itemprop="url">Hooville</a>
        <div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
         <meta itemprop="addressLocality" content="Anystate, USA">
       </div>
   </div>`

- or you go the way of JSON-LD and write the JSON-LD snippet into the head of the page like

`{
  "@context": {
    "schema": "http://schema.org/"
  },
  "@graph": [
    {
      "@id": "_:Nf4d71df24b5444298f9c170e1337ec1b",
      "@type": "schema:PostalAddress",
      "schema:addressLocality": "Anystate, USA"
    },
    {
      "@id": "",
      "rdfa:usesVocabulary": {
        "@id": "schema:"
      }
    },
    {
      "@id": "_:N980cf56db1b7422b80fd7c37ed95951e",
      "@type": "https://schema.org/Place",
      "https://schema.org/address": {
        "@id": "_:Nf4d71df24b5444298f9c170e1337ec1b"
      },
      "https://schema.org/name": "Hooville",
      "https://schema.org/url": {
        "@id": "http://www.example.com"
      }
    }
  ]
}`

Comment: Do you know of any negative effects based on this policy from Google: "The meta tag should not be used to hide content that is not visible to users in any form, since it might create misleading or deceptive search experience." - https://developers.google.com/structured-data/policies

Comment: it always depends on how you use it. Google is able to see misusage. But i personally haven't seen any negative impact of it.

Comment: @ElendilTheTall: Regarding the "negative effects", my answer about [using Microdata with `meta`/`link` elements for Schema.org](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/82114/17633) might be relevant.